# How to convert HTML content to byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to convert HTML Content string to byte[] then convert this into msword document. but in my doc I am getting some special character added instead of Space or " ". Please look at my code below. Please some one help.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HtmlContent));
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF-8");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = FileName + ".doc"
        };
```

Comment: I do not see any conversion code here. You cannot just save html to a file with .doc extension and then expect it to _be_ a .doc ...

Comment: Converting html to word format is not trivial. At least not if you want to preserve any kind of layout or formatting. So you would likely need to use something like [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/demos.html)

Comment: You might try changing the file extension to .html (instead of .doc) and see if Word will open it and convert it for you. There's a slim chance that could work, although I expect the behavior would be highly browser-dependent. Plus any images, stylesheets, or other content used by the HTML page might not load correctly. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Ok. This is my ASP.Net web api project and here i am trying to give the downloadable .doc file as the API response. That is working as expected but the format of the doc file is not proper

Comment: I was thinking like there must be some encoding is missing while converting in to byte[]

Comment: because of that its not formatting properly

Comment: Going from Html to .doc is not a matter of encoding, You don't seem to understand what the other comments are saying.

Comment: I think convert html to .doc file is to complex, why do not just return `"text/html"` type? Just refer to this [link](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-webapi-return-html/)

Answer (score 0):

After remove certain character from html content using Regex word document started working.

```
htmlTemplate = Regex.Replace(htmlTemplate, @"(?<=<[^>]*)&nbsp;", "").Trim();
htmlTemplate = Regex.Replace(htmlTemplate, @"\s{2,}", "");
htmlTemplate = Regex.Replace(htmlTemplate, @"\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```